# Is there a minimalist way to get a default ResourceBundle when you do not need localization?

Tags: java, logging, resourcebundle, java.util.logging

I want to inherit to extend `java.util.logging.Logger`.  The only visible constructor is

```
protected Logger(String name, String resourceBundleName)
```

This is despite the fact that when you want to get an instance, they offer two ways:

```
static Logger   getLogger(String name)
static Logger   getLogger(String name, String resourceBundleName)
```

Is there a way to obtain some sort of default `ResourceBundle` or default name of a `ResourceBundle` so that I can use the constructor without creating an internationalization properties file and associated object?

Of course I could simply produce a wrapper class and use `getLogger(String name)` to avoid the need for the `ResourceBundle` name.  Unfortunately that means I would have to implement a wrapper method for every `Logger` method I want to use.  (Too much typing).

**Edit:** The following attempt to get the default localization data from Logger does not work.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class JLogger extends Logger
{
    static Logger dummyLogger = Logger.getLogger("com.dummy.utilities");

    private JLogger(String name)
    {
        super(name, JLogger.dummyLogger.getResourceBundleName());
    }

    static JLogger getJLogger(String name)
    {
        return new JLogger(name);
    }

    public void severe() // a zero arguments version of severe
    {
        severe("");
    }
}
```

The `getResourceBundleName()` just returns a null.  The `super(name, resourceName)` constructor builds something which does not do any logging if the second argument is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately that means I would have to implement a wrapper method for every Logger method I want to use. (Too much typing).

No need to do that, it's been done already.  Have a look at [SLF4J](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=slf4j&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.slf4j.org/&ei=57avTpC2E8eD-wbW_cC2Ag&usg=AFQjCNEcMpiXAjIDjIVe-yjiBy8oQ_QJGA&cad=rja) and [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/), they provide sensible wrappers around java.util.logging, hiding the awfulness of that API.

Those two APIs can also delegate to a proper underlying log implementation such as Logback or Log4J, bypassing java.util.logging altogether.